# Interop word: Is there a way to add multiple table (or paragraphs) into a table cell without having them merged together?

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, interop, office-interop

I have a problem adding multiple paragraph or tables to a table cell. They all merge together.

[Result]

[image: 1]

- I want my two tables to be one after each other and not merged in my cell range
- I want the text in red (I've put in red in word) to be my tables titles, I added before in my code and it still appears after.

here is my code:

```
Paragraph pBT_Text = document.Paragraphs.Add(cell.Range);
pBT_Text.Range.Font.Bold = 1;
pBT_Text.Range.Font.Size = 7;
pBT_Text.Range.Font.Underline = WdUnderline.wdUnderlineSingle;
pBT_Text.Range.Text = "x-content";
pBT_Text.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

Paragraph pIntroTable_BT = document.Paragraphs.Add(cell.Range);
Table Bt_Tech_Table = document.Tables.Add(pIntroTable_BT.Range, 5, 7, ref missing, ref missing);
Bt_Tech_Table.Borders.Enable = 1;
Bt_Tech_Table.Range.Font.Underline = WdUnderline.wdUnderlineNone;
Bt_Tech_Table.Range.Paragraphs.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
Bt_Tech_Table.AllowAutoFit = true;

Bt_Tech_Table.Rows[1].Cells[1].Range.Text += "x-content";
Bt_Tech_Table.Rows[1].Cells[1].Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = WdColor.wdColorLightTurquoise;

Bt_Tech_Table.Rows[1].Cells[2].Range.Text += "x-content";
Bt_Tech_Table.Rows[1].Cells[2].Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = WdColor.wdColorLightGreen;

Bt_Tech_Table.Rows[1].Cells[3].Range.Text += "x-content";
Bt_Tech_Table.Rows[1].Cells[3].Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = WdColor.wdColorLightBlue;

Bt_Tech_Table.Rows[1].Cells[4].Range.Text += "x-content";
Bt_Tech_Table.Rows[1].Cells[4].Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = WdColor.wdColorLavender;

Bt_Tech_Table.Rows[1].Cells[5].Range.Text += "x-content";
Bt_Tech_Table.Rows[1].Cells[5].Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = WdColor.wdColorLightOrange;

Bt_Tech_Table.Rows[1].Cells[6].Range.Text += "x-content";
Bt_Tech_Table.Rows[1].Cells[6].Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = WdColor.wdColorLightYellow;

Bt_Tech_Table.Rows[1].Cells[7].Range.Text += "x-content";
Bt_Tech_Table.Rows[1].Cells[7].Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = WdColor.wdColorGray35;

Bt_Tech_Table.Columns.AutoFit();

for ( int i =0; i< 4; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
    {
        cell.Range.Font.Bold = 0;
        Bt_Tech_Table.Rows[i+2].Cells[j+1].Range.Text += this.dgv_BT.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();

        if ((i+2) == 5 || (j+1) == 7)
        {
            Bt_Tech_Table.Rows[i + 2].Cells[j + 1].Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = WdColor.wdColorGray35;
        }
    }
}

pIntroTable_BT.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

Paragraph pMP_Text = document.Paragraphs.Add(cell.Range);
pMP_Text.Range.Font.Bold = 1;
pMP_Text.Range.Font.Size = 7;
pMP_Text.Range.Font.Underline = WdUnderline.wdUnderlineSingle;
pMP_Text.Range.Text = "x-content";
pMP_Text.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

Paragraph pIntroTable_MP = document.Paragraphs.Add(cell.Range);
Table Bt_MP_Table = document.Tables.Add(pIntroTable_MP.Range, 2, 5, ref missing, ref missing);
Bt_MP_Table.Borders.Enable = 1;
Bt_MP_Table.Range.Font.Underline = WdUnderline.wdUnderlineNone;
Bt_MP_Table.Range.Paragraphs.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
Bt_MP_Table.AllowAutoFit = true;

Bt_MP_Table.Rows[1].Cells[1].Range.Text += "x-content";
Bt_MP_Table.Rows[1].Cells[1].Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = WdColor.wdColorLightTurquoise;

Bt_MP_Table.Rows[1].Cells[2].Range.Text += "x-content";
Bt_MP_Table.Rows[1].Cells[2].Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = WdColor.wdColorLightGreen;

Bt_MP_Table.Rows[1].Cells[3].Range.Text += "x-content";
Bt_MP_Table.Rows[1].Cells[3].Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = WdColor.wdColorLightBlue;

Bt_MP_Table.Rows[1].Cells[4].Range.Text += "x-content";
Bt_MP_Table.Rows[1].Cells[4].Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = WdColor.wdColorLavender;

Bt_MP_Table.Rows[1].Cells[5].Range.Text += "x-content";
Bt_MP_Table.Rows[1].Cells[5].Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = WdColor.wdColorLightOrange;

Bt_MP_Table.Columns.AutoFit();

for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
{
    Bt_MP_Table.Rows[2].Cells[j + 1].Range.Text += this.dgv_Crit.Rows[0].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
}
pIntroTable_MP.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
```

I've tried a lot of manipulation with Ranges, adding of paragraph, trying to understand a way to do it. So far the only legit way I succeed to place them as I wish, is by adding the paragraphs without references to the cell.Range.

I know tables does "eat" the range entirely, that is why I thought using different paragraphs would make it.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Where is cell.Range defined? Surely you would need to advance the destination range object in some way?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman my bad I should've include all of the code, I wanted to keep it a bit more simple: cell.Range is defined earlier like this:

`foreach (Row row in My_Table.Rows){
         switch (row.Index)
    {
        case 1:
            foreach(Cell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                if (cell.ColumnIndex == 1)
                {
                    cell.Range.Font.Bold = 1;

[...]`